# How to set value in with Beautiful Soup in some HTML element if I know id of that element or class?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to set value with Beautiful Soup in some element if I know id of that  HTML element or class ?
For example I have

`<td id="test"></td`>

and I want to set text RESTORE... like

`<td id="test">RESTORE...</td>`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Find the tag you want to modify using a `find()` search for `id=test`. Then:

[BeautifulSoup Documentation - "Modifying the tree"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree)

> **Modifying .string**
>
> If you set a tag’s .string attribute, the tag’s contents are replaced with the string you give:

```
markup = '<a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)

tag = soup.a
tag.string = "New link text."
tag
# <a href="http://example.com/">New link text.</a>
```

> Be careful: if the tag contained other tags, they and all their contents will be destroyed.

Comment: @Phalgun: If you try to assign an integer to a string property, you will have a bad time. What is surprising about that?

Comment: Should have framed my sentence better. My initial comment was meant to be a heads up to the reader. Also, how do I actually set an integer as the value of the tag.

Comment: @Phalgun: Since this is HTML, there is no such thing as an integer value - it is all text, in the end. So you likely want to do something like: `tag.string = str(1)`, which will cause the text to be set to the string `"1"`.

Comment: It doesn't work if the new value is another tags :/ E.g. it translates every `<` to `&lt`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: That's because a `.string` is not a `tag`. Try http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup-new-string-and-new-tag .

Comment: Thank you, but no, that didn't worked. The `new_string` does the same thing, and the `new_tag` do not allows to pass a list of tags with contents and other tags.

Comment: Aha, I found a workaround — I need to create from every such a text new `BeautifulSoup` with the second argument `"html.parser"` to not allow it put a `html`n`body` tags, next I have to just `append()` it. Thx tho.