# How to change make changes and update source code using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
result=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4'}).text
print(soup.prettify())

n=list(d.values())[0]
print(n)
result=n
soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4'}).text=result
#print(soup.prettify())
```

I'm getting an error like below:

```py
soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4'}).text=result
     64 #print(soup.prettify())

**AttributeError: can't set attribute**
```

Basically I want to some changes in the source code
then also updating the url with updated source code

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: Hard to tell what you're trying to achieve, but the error is clear; You are attempting to set `soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4'}).text` to `result`, which you can't

Comment: It is just a URL

Comment: Guys just think of a site's URL where text field , the script can edit the text in field without visiting the website

Comment: I want to replace the string in the text field and updates the source code ...so that when someone visits the latest data is shown instead of old one .

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this to replace the string element:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
result=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4'}).text
print(soup.prettify())

n=list(d.values())[0]
print(n)
result=n
ele = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4'}).findChildren()[-1]
ele.string.replace_with(n)
#print(soup.prettify())
```

**Example 1:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

d = {0:'Bar',2:'Baz',3:'Qux'}


page = """
<div class="entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4">Foo</a>
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
result=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4'}).text
print(soup.prettify())

n=list(d.values())[0]
#print(n)
result=n
ele = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4'})
ele.string.replace_with(n)
print(soup.prettify())
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4">
 Foo
</div>

<div class="entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4">
 Bar
</div>
```

**Example 2:**

This will raise that error as the `ele.string` returns `None` as the there are multiple tags under `<article>` so can't get `.string` attribute

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

d = {0:'Bar',2:'Baz',3:'Qux'}


page = """
<article> <div><p>Hello</p></div> </article> 
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
result=soup.find('article').text
print(soup.prettify())

n=list(d.values())[0]
#print(n)
result=n
ele = soup.find('article')
ele.string.replace_with(n)
print(soup.prettify())
```

But this will work since `ele.string` returns `' Hello '`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

d = {0:'Bar',2:'Baz',3:'Qux'}


page = """
<article> <div><p>Hello</p></div> </article> 
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
result=soup.find('article').text
print(soup.prettify())

n=list(d.values())[0]
#print(n)
result=n
ele = soup.find('p')
ele.string.replace_with(n)
print(soup.prettify())
```

And finally, you can use the `.findChildren()`, to access that end node.

Comment: Using ur code gives this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'

Comment: ok. so that means `soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'entry-text my-2 px-2 px-sm-4'})` is returning `None`. Can you share the html? (specifically what is `page`)

Comment: <article>
<div><p>Hello</p></div>
</article> something likes this . I want to replace hello

Comment: make sure you're getting the leaf end tag. see my example 2 above

Comment: Try that original block code aboce (with the added `.findChildren()`), see if that does it.

Comment: I've done the thing but I also wanted the URL to be updated for real so that when someone visits the URL it shows the updated data

Comment: The thing is updated source code must be reflected in the old url

Comment: not sure what you mean by that. have to update the html filename that youre publishing then (and adjust any links that reference to that page).

Comment: I have updated the text in the source code but I want the same thing to be reflected in old URL with new text

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of BeautifulSoup is scraping data from the given HTML, not routing to update things on HTML.

I think `.text` returns an immutable variable, which is `read-only`. However, if you want to change the string in a particular tag, you can refer to the answer in this post ([How to set value in with Beautiful Soup in some HTML element if I know id of that element or class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766966/how-to-set-value-in-with-beautiful-soup-in-some-html-element-if-i-know-id-of-tha)).

If you also have the routing part to render HTML files, you can use the modified result there to update changes in the UI.